# Property x does not exist ob type 'void | Value'

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have a function that returns sometimes:

Promise < Value > (if is no error),

Promise < void > if the error exists.

```
async function myFunction(
  a: A
  b: B
) {
  try {
    const variable = await getSomething(a,b);
    return getValue(variable);
  } catch(e) {
    return throwError(e);
  }
}
```

My trowError function looks like:

```
export default function throwError(error: Error | any) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
        throw error;
    }
    throw new Error(String(error));
}
```

I did `type MyType = Promise<Value | void>`;

And put above line as return type to myFunction and it does not trigger an error there.

But if I tried to use some values from the function in another one, I face error that says:

***Property val1 does not exist ob type 'void | Value'***

```
async function anotherFunction() {
  // do some stuff
  const { val1 } = await myFunction(x, y);
  // do rest stuff
}
```

Please about some help or advise!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `throwError` function returns `never`:

```
export default function throwError(error: Error | any) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
        throw error;
    }
    throw new Error(String(error));
}
```

since it **never returns**. That means `myFunction` actually returns `Promise<Value | never>`, but since `never` is the *empty union type*, it gets reduced to `Promise<Value>`:

```
async function myFunction(
  a: A
  b: B
): Promise<Value> {
  try {
    const variable = await getSomething(a,b);
    return getValue(variable);
  } catch(e) {
    return throwError(e);
  }
}
```

Also, I don't think you need an explicit type annotation here. TypeScript should be able to infer the return type of this function.

Comment: My throwError returns void instead of never. At least, I see it when hover on the name of the function.

Comment: @karo-s Well, I just tested in the playground and that seems to be the case... That's weird since it *should* be `never`, since it can't return (as it always throws). Maybe a TS bug? In any case, the return type of `myFunction` should be `Promise<Value>`.